# Como percorrer uma lista encadeada a partir da ultima posição?

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Estou com uma dúvida a respeito de lista encadeada em C. O exercício é uma função que recebe como parâmetro o nodo inicial da lista encadeada e a posição x (contando de trás para frente). Com isso, tenho que após percorrer e achar a posição, retornar o valor do nodo correspondente.

Fiz isso até agora:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
}
/*-------------------------------------------------*/

int GetNode(Node *head,int positionFromTail)
{
    struct Node* fimNodo;
    while(head->next!=NULL){
        head->next=next;
        if(head->next==NULL){

            fimNodo->data=head->data;
            fimNodo->next=head->next;
        }

    }
    while(positionFromTail!=0){
        fimNodo->next=*next;
        positionFromTail--;
        if(positionFromTail==0){
            return fimNodo->data;
        }
    }
}
```

Está dando erro nessa função. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Obs: O exercício é apenas essa função e não necessita a função principal...

Os erros que estão ocorrendo são:

```
cannot resolve overloaded function ‘next’ based on conversion to type ‘Node*’


cannot convert ‘Node’ to ‘Node*’ in assignment
```

Comment: poderia especificar qual erro está ocorrendo?

Comment: cannot resolve overloaded function ‘next’ based on conversion to type ‘Node*’,          base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘Node’,        base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘Node’,    base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘Node’ ,    isso ocorre  a partir do segundo while.

Comment: Amigo, coloque a mensagem de erro editando a questão. É horrível de ler código nos comentários

Comment: Vi que tu atualizaste o código... Editei agora para formatar melhor. Mas falta saber onde é inicializada a variável `next`, usadas no início dos loops. Se eu tentar compilar, vai dar variável não declarada...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro do comentário, basicamente, é que tu declaraste `struct Node fimNodo;` como variável estática, e não como ponteiro.

Use:

```
struct Node* fimNodo;
```

para poder usar `fimNodo->next` out `fimNodo->data`.

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal consegui!!!

O código ficou assim:

```
int GetNode(struct Node *head, int positionFromTail)
{
    int x = 0, y = 2;
    struct Node *fimNodo = head;

    if (fimNodo == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    while (fimNodo != NULL) {
        fimNodo = fimNodo->next;
        x++;
    }

    x = x - positionFromTail;
    fimNodo = head;

    while (y <= x) {
        fimNodo = fimNodo->next;
        y++;
    }   

    return fimNodo->data;
}
```

OBS:
 Resumidamente adicionei 2 contadores (x e y). Um para percorrer a lista encadeada para ver o total de posições (x) e outro para achar a posição necessária. Fiz a comparação para ver se a lista estava vazia, etc.